# Are annotations supported by Python 2.6.x

Tags: python, junit4

I am referring to JUnit annotations like @test, @before , @after.

e.g i can write a method:

```
@Ignore("Not Ready to Run")
    @Test
     multiplication():
                self.assertEqual('15', simpleMath.multiply(3, 5))
```

Comment: Those look like decorators, which are supported in Python 2.6. You'll need to import them from wherever they're defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax is called decorator in python 2.6.  I'm not sure whether it is the same thing as an innotation though.